# itemWithNormalSprite with block on cocos2d for ios

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocos2d-iphone

I'm trying to create a `MenuItem` that would move to gameplay using a block and not a selector (working on cocos2d for IOS v2.0)

```
CCMenuItemSprite *nextLevelMI = [CCMenuItemSprite itemWithNormalSprite:playSpr selectedSprite:playSpr2 block:^(id sender)block];
```

Can anyone give me an example for such use?

10x, Shefy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example with CCMenuItemLabel. Apart from the other parameters it's no different than CCMenuItemSprite usage. I assume you want to see how to use the block.

```
CCMenuItem* item = [CCMenuItemLabel itemWithLabel:label block:^(id sender)
{
    CCScene* scene = [PixelPerfectTouchScene node];
    [ReturnToMainMenuNode returnNodeWithParent:scene];
    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene:scene];
}];
```

[More examples here](https://github.com/LearnCocos2D/LearnCocos2D/tree/master/Cocos2D-CCRenderTexture-Demo/Cocos2D-CCRenderTexture-Demo), in MainMenuScene and ReturnToMainMenuNode for example.